# Parent method with extra arguments in Python

Tags: python, oop

**Parent class** has a property called 'deserialize' that is *static and abstract* with one argument. Each **Child class** implemented that method. Now I have a situation that Child class needs more than one argument. When I add `options=None` to Parent class, children classes complain that they have a different signature(warning). I have to add `options=None` to each class. That is a refactoring. I want to know if I can omit the warning and continue, or there is a better solution? Or do I have to refactor?

```
class Serializable:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def deserialize(json_obj, options=None):
        pass

class ChildWithNoExtraArguments(Serializable):

   # warning is here...
   @staticmethod        
   def deserialize(json_obj):
        # some implementation

class ChildWithExtraArgumnets(Serializable):

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(json_obj, options):
        # some implementation, I need options
```

Comment: Why is the method static?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice because of the OOP conditions. I mean we need that be static.

Comment: What OOP conditions?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean: [When to use static method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2671529/4360116)

Comment: A link doesn't answer my question

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You asked why static method. It is clear. In my situation deserialize method is not associated to any instance. It doesn't need an instance to do it's behavior. It is class level method.

Comment: If it was clear, I wouldn't have had to ask. I am trying to understand what you are doing so that I can help you find a solution. Thank you for finally answering my question directly and clearly.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am really sorry for my bad answering :(

Comment: No need to apologize. Just remember that clear and direct answers are often the most helpful on this site. I think Matt has answered your question better than I can, so I will leave off here. Good luck to you in your programming endeavors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decorate your child classes `deserialize` implementation with `@staticmethod` too. The exception you're seeing is because python is automatically adding `self` to each of the method calls. Decorating then with `@staticmethod` stops this behavior.

Additionally, you're second implementation needs to define options as a keyword argument. Keyword arguments have default values, for instance: `options=None`.

```
class Serializable:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def deserialize(json_obj, options=None):
        pass

class ChildWithNoExtraArguments(Serializable):

   # warning is here...        
    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(json_obj, options=None):
        # some implementation

class ChildWithExtraArgumnets(Serializable):

    @staticmethod
    def deserialize(json_obj, options=None):
        # some implementation, I need options
```

Comment: Sorry, I added @staticmethod to subclasses. I updated my question.

Comment: We're almost there. I updated my response to address your other issue. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can do this. I have to refactor all of my methods. So maybe this is the only solution.

Comment: you could use the `deserialize(json_obj, **kwargs)` to suck up options, and any other keyword arguments. The `**` is a bit of syntax that tells Python to put any remaining keyword arguments into a dictionary named kwargs.